# Exception error

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have developed an app which turns the device in silent mode and back to normal on given times set by the user. User will enter the name of the event then input start and end time and then click the create button to create the event. I ran the app and user selects the start time at this spot my app crashes and throws an exception which I am unable to understand. I am posting the  related code below and the exception error.

[snapshot of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imIqW.png)

Exception error

```
10-22 19:13:52.538 13334-13334/applications.recyclerview1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: applications.recyclerview1, PID: 13334
                                                                        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=17; index=19
                                                                            at java.util.Calendar.get(Calendar.java:903)
                                                                            at applications.recyclerview1.MainActivity$3.onTimeSet(MainActivity.java:95)
                                                                            at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:133)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5669)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

10-22 19:13:52.588 13334-13334/applications.recyclerview1 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13334 SIG: 9
MainActivity.java

```
public void start(View view)
{
    // Get Current Time
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

   final Calendar newobj=Calendar.getInstance();

    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


                    start.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    newobj.get(hourOfDay);
                    newobj.get(minute);

                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    //create a pending intent to be called at midnight
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pending Intent started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    PendingIntent midnightPI = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent("applications.recyclerview1.SilenceBroadCastReceiver"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    //schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day

                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newobj.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, midnightPI);

                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}

public void end(View view)
{
    // Get Current Time
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    final Calendar newobj2=Calendar.getInstance();

    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {

                    end.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    newobj2.get(hourOfDay);
                    newobj2.get(minute);


                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    PendingIntent sixPI = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent("applications.recyclerview1.UnsilenceBroadcastReceiver"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    //schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day

                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newobj2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sixPI);

                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="applications.recyclerview1">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".View_Foods"></activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SilenceBroadCastReceiver">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="applications.recyclerview1.SilenceBroadCastReceiver" >

            </action>

        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".UnsilenceBroadcastReceiver">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="applications.recyclerview1.UnsilenceBroadcastReceiver" >

            </action>

        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</application>
```

SilenceBroadCastReceiver.java

```
public class SilenceBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}}
```

UnsilentBroadCastReceiver.java

```
public class UnsilenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
}}
```

Comment: where is your exception stacktrace ??

Comment: You should post your log with error as text.

Comment: @DimaKozhevin I have added the log its not good formated but please tell me where is the mistake

Comment: @zainulabidin Thanks for improving your question.

Comment: you are welcome @DimaKozhevin any solution?

Comment: @zainulabidin Did you try suggested solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46873756/3166697?

Comment: now my app is not crashing I have implemented the solution of @DeepLathia and it works fine but my device didn't got silent at a time....could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following this way for your required process:

```
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    myTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


            Calendar newTime = Calendar.getInstance();

            //newTime.set(hourOfDay, minute); // remove this line

            //Add these two line
            newTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            newTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

            GotTime = GotDate + " At " + String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + " :" + String.valueOf(minute + 1);
            time.setText(GotTime);
        }
    }, calender.get((Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
}
```

Comment: but somehow my device didn't got silent at that time could you help me with that

Comment: I am passing newTime in my pending intent as newTime.gettimeinmillis